# Populating a GridView from a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new ASP.NET and I have never used a GridView or DataGrid, but I cannot find helpful examples online on how to do what I need. I need some data to be displayed on a page and I know that I should use a GridView, but I cannot seem to get anything to display.

I have the following DataSet:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyTables");
ds.Tables.Add("Users");
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("ID");
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("Name");
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("Email");
ds.Tables["Users"].Rows.Add(0,"Ace","ace@example.com");
ds.Tables["Users"].Rows.Add(1,"Biff","biff@example.com");
ds.Tables["Users"].Rows.Add(2,"Chuck","chuck@example.com");
ds.Tables["Users"].Rows.Add(3,"Dick","dick@example.com");
myGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables["Users"].DefaultView;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

Heres is my ASP.NET:

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You're adding Chuck and Dick with the same ID (2).

Comment: If you want to get technical, he's also missing closing parens on four of his lines. Won't even build like that.

Comment: After the fix of all my typos, this still does not seem to work. Is the ASP.NET code correct?

Comment: There must be some other code that is causing the issue.  I pasted your dataset code into the Page_Load event of a fresh page and it works perfectly.  Where is code that populates the dataset currently executed?

Comment: The problem was that my table was empty. Who do I pick for the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that you're getting a object null reference error. What's happening is that you're creating columns in a table called 'add users' where there is no table called 'add users'. If you just change the three lines that you have ds.Tables["Add Users"] and change that to just ds.Tables["Users"] everything should work out just fine.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I guess I should have added that you would need to bind the gridview in the page_load event or have a method which has this binding code in it and have the method called somehow. (Page Load, button click, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're adding columns to the wrong table. Try something like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyTables");
ds.Tables.Add("Users");
DataTable userTable = ds.Tables["Users"];
userTable.Columns.Add("ID");
userTable.Columns.Add("Name");
userTable.Columns.Add("Email");
userTable.Rows.Add(0,"Ace","ace@example.com)";
userTable.Rows.Add(1,"Biff","biff@example.com)";
userTable.Rows.Add(2,"Chuck","chuck@example.com)";
userTable.Rows.Add(2,"Dick","dick@example.com)";
myGrid.DataSource = userTable;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing two completely different tables. You create the Table USERS then add columns to a table called ADD USERS then add rows to the Users table. Nothing will show up when you bind this.

Change this code

```
ds.Tables["Add Users"].Columns.Add("ID");
ds.Tables["Add Users"].Columns.Add("Name");
ds.Tables["Add Users"].Columns.Add("Email");
```

to this

```
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("ID");
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("Name");
ds.Tables["Users"].Columns.Add("Email");
```